# How to fix the keyboard in application in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have this application which animates two `ImageViews`... I manage to use `Menu` key to disappear one of the `ImageViews` because it can be used irrespective of softkeyboard. Here is the code..

```
public class Client extends Activity {

    private ImageView mScanner, mScanner2;
    private Animation mAnimation;
    private InputMethodManager mgr ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mScanner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        mScanner2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500);
        mAnimation.setDuration(10000);
        mAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        mScanner2.setAnimation(mAnimation);
        mScanner.setAnimation(mAnimation);
        mScanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mScanner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(et.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            System.out.println(" Menu Clicked");
            mScanner.setAnimation(null);
            mScanner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            System.out.println(" A ");
            mScanner2.setAnimation(null);
            mScanner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want keyboard to be fixed at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Your goal is to show the keyboard right?

Comment: @Milos Yes, thats right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private InputMethodManager mgr;

mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

fixed the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

In the manifest for your activity there is  configChanges. If this is not set then events like this (keyboard pulling, orientation change etc.) will restart your activity.
Do customize configChanges according to what you want.